# Which codecs should I install on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, video, codec

I'm with a refresh Snow Leopard install. What Codec Pack (for DivX, XviD, etc) should I install?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Perian](http://www.perian.org/) is a codec pack that will suit most of your needs.
- Alternatively, if you install [VLC](http://www.videolan.org), you can use that player to play almost all video formats you can throw at it.
- Installing [Windows Media Components for QuickTime](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/player/wmcomponents.mspx) (Flip4Mac) enables you to play Windows media files.

Comment: With VLC, I don't need to install codecs? It have them?

Comment: @zote That's right, you don't need to install additional codec packs with VLC. From the VLC website: "It doesn't need any external codec, program or codec pack to work."